# How to configure fileIdEncoding =1 in recordIndexMetadata in Apche Hudi metaDataTable

Tags: apache-hudi

I'm working with Apache Hudi and need to set the fileIdEncoding parameter to 1 for a specific use case involving file ID manipulation. I understand that fileIdEncoding influences how file IDs are derived and stored, When it is set to 0, Hudi uses fileIdHighBits, fileIdLowBits And fileIndex to derive the fileId, but fileIdEncoding = 1, documentation says it should give the string of file ID directly, But I can't find how to set this property in documentation.

Could someone guide me on how to correctly configure this in Hudi? Is it done through the Hudi configuration file, or is there a specific method to set this parameter programmatically?

Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated. Below is the Documentation link!
[text](https://hudi.apache.org/tech-specs/#metadata)